# Is the memory snooping possible against the Intel architecture?

Tags: memory, x86, hardware, intel

I am interested in developing external hardware monitor in Intel architecture.

I want to know if it is possible to snoop the bus between the CPU and DRAM to know which physical address is being read or written.

In other words, can we attach any devices to the motherboard or use other devices such as graphics card to snoop the bus to know which memory area is accessed by the CPU?

---

The reason I want to use the hardware approach is we don't fully trust the kernel or hypervisor which translate the VA to PA under our threat model.

Comment: To clarify: you want to check the DRAM bus to see when the DRAM bus isn't used (because the cache saves a bus access)? I have no clue why that could work.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, DRAM is accessed as a cache line unit (64bytes), and I want to know which physical memory is accessed by the read access from the system software. The reason I want to use the hardware approach is we couldn't believe the kernel or hypervisor which translate the VA to PA under our threat model

Comment: @MSalters: "cache line" was being used to refer to a block of memory of that size, being loaded or stored.  I initially wasn't sure either, so I fixed the wording to ask what I think the OP intended.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to run the untrusted kernel/hypervisor in a virtual machine itself, and then attach a debugger to the VM. In other words, add a layer of software indirection to avoid making this a hardware problem.

Comment: The kernel or hypervisor doesn't do the VA/PA translation anyway, so that's another broken assumption it seems. (The CPU does the translation, would be far too slow in SW).